# Syntax error on token "eqn" delete this token

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, double, token

I am fairly new to Java and taking a course but cannot figure out this small syntax error that I keep on getting. I have been researching and staring at the problem for a while now and just cannot figure it out. I am not asking for someone to complete the project just need help with this 1 error. Sorry if I am not posting in the right section. Below is the code....

```
import java.util.*;
public class SolveEqu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        double arr[]=new double[3];  //passing array as parameter
        System.out.println("Enter the three coefficients of the equation separated by spaces");

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            arr[i]=sc.nextDouble();     

        double result[]=solveQuadratic(arr); // unknown   

        //if result is negative
        if(result.length==1) {                 
            System.out.println("The equation has no real roots");
        }
             
        //if result is = to zero
        else if(result.length==2) {      
            System.out.println(" The equation has just one real root");
            System.out.format("The root is %.2f",result[1]);
        }
             
        //if result is positive
        else                               
        {
            System.out.println("The equation has two real roots");
            System.out.format("The root are %.2f and %.2f",result[1],result[2]);    
         }
    }

    public static double[] solveQuadratic(double[] eqn) {  // method heading from assignment

        double discriminant=eqn[1]eqn[1]-(4eqn[0]eqn[2]);  // discriminant of the quadratic equation
        if(discriminant>0) {                  //   discriminant is positive and has 2 real roots       
            double r1=(-eqn[1]+Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2eqn[0]);   // equation for square roots
            double r2=(-eqn[1]-Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2eqn[0]);  //equation for square roots
            double res[]= {2,r1,r2};      
            return res;
        }
        else if(discriminant==0)  //equal to zero the equation has just one real root          
        {
            double r1=(-eqn[1])/(2eqn[0]);  
            double res[]= {1,r1};             
            return res;
        }
        else     //   the equation has no real roots 
        {
            double res[]= {0};    //unknown  
            return res;    //unknown 
        }
    }
}
```

The line that is causing me trouble and  throwing errors on is the following ...

```
double discriminant=eqn[1]eqn[1]-(4eqn[0]eqn[2]);
```

It says "Invalid float literal number" and "Syntax error on taken "eqn", delete this token"

Could someone help explain what this error means?

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?! Are you missing the mathematical operators?

Comment: `eqn[1]eqn[1]` is not a valid statement. If you want the values to be multiplied, you need to use `eqn[1]*eqn[1]`

Comment: Ahh got it thanks - I overlooked that you needed syntax between those two. I was able to fix that now only seeing an error on -(4eqn[0] - is that not a valid statement either bit confused on that

Comment: it's the same issue. What do you expect `4eqn[0]` to be?

Comment: Basically, we are taking and finding the square roots of a quadratic equation and for the specific portion we are looking at and having trouble with is converting b2 (squared) - 4ac. Does that make sense or not? Hard to explain

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @f1sh was the first of multiple examples of the same problem.

As pointed out, you needed a multiplication operator for `eqn[1]*eqn[1]`.

For `4eqn[0]eqn[2]`, the same applies.  If I remember my quadratics, you are trying to multiply there, so you need `4*eqn[0]*eqn[2]`.  The line should read:

```
double discriminant=eqn[1]*eqn[1]-(4*eqn[0]*eqn[2]);
```

Similarly, in your calculation for `r1` and `r2`, `2eqn[0]` should be `2*eqn[0]`.  That fix is needed in both places you calculate `r1`.

So, the basic rule is that, in java, you must specify the operator between two symbols.  Unlike in math, writing them next to one another does not imply multiplication.